# Appium Setup - no ./reset.sh file

Tags: android, ios, appium, functional-testing

I am attempting to set up [Appium](http://appium.io/) and am following the [tutorial](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#install-ruby).

I get to the `cd appium; ./reset.sh` line in **Install Ruby** section. I don't have a `reset.sh` file anywhere. I've installed all prior steps, as well as `XCode` and `Android Dev Studio`.

So I tried to skip over that step, and simply run appium with `node .`, which throws error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myname/Sites/myproject/appium

Obviously it needs a `server.js` or `app.js` file, but the `git clone git://github.com/appium/appium.git` repo clone did not come with one.

I'm not sure which other steps I should take to get Appium started. I simply want to get it running so I can start writing test functional test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Install homebrew:

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Uninstall home-brew:
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

2. Install node and npm:

   brew install node
3. Install appium:

   npm install -g appium

To start the appium server, run:
    appium

HOW TO FIX ERROR: ENOENT LSTAT NPM WHEN TRYING TO INSTALL MODULES

npm cache clean

error: uncaughtException: fn must be a function

To fix this upgrade node or uninstall node and install node and appium again
brew uninstall node
brew upgrade node
and then install npm again

4. ios-webkit-debug-proxy installation and use, refer: 
   https://github.com/penguinho/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/ios-webkit-debug-proxy.md
   https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy
   https://github.com/jchuong/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Install ios-webkit-debug-proxy only in iOS to enable appium to switch to web view context.
brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy

NOTE: the proxy requires the "web inspector" to be turned on to allow a connection to be established. Turn it on by going to settings > safari > advanced > web inspector - On. Please be aware that the web inspector was added as part of iOS 6 and was not available previously.

5. brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller